# Log IP address using netcat

Tags: linux, terminal, netcat

How to log IP address every time which is connected to the port, I'm using nc to listen and tee to append in a log file
[image]

```
netcat -lkv -W2 -p 4000 | tee -a /tmp/netcat.log
```